# Bootstrap 4 Beta - Smooth Scrolling with ScrollSpy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with making my anchors smooth-scroll to target text. I've tried using jQuery from other answered questions on here but that simply doesn't work for some odd reason.

No luck with ScrollSpy either. I'm using this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_scrollspy.asp) of ScrollSpy SmoothScrolling from W3Schools.

And this is my markup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tbd.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/hover-min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="pattern-svg-background">
  <div class="col-xl-1-12|auto">
    <div id="top" class="jumbotron">
      <h1 class="display-3">Hello there,buddy!</h1>
      <p class="lead">It is time to choose a browser but there are so many great choices that you get confused on what to pick! </p>
      <hr class="m-y-md">
      <p>This is where I come in! I'm going to explain the pros and cons of most popular(and less popular) browsers. Pick your browser in the menu below!</p>
      <p class="lead">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light rounded mb-3">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav text-md-center nav-justified w-100">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#chrome"><i class="fa fa-chrome fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Google Chrome<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#opera"><i class="fa fa-opera fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Opera</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#safari"><i class="fa fa-safari fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Safari</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#firefox"><i class="fa fa-firefox fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Firefox</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#edge"><i class="fa fa-edge fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edge</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Other browsers</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#other">Vivaldi</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#other">Midori</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#other">Pale Moon</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-browser-info-text container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2 id="chrome">Google Chrome</h2>
        <p class="browser-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis vehicula neque. Phasellus consequat risus sed magna hendrerit venenatis. Nulla maximus magna eu velit vestibulum, at aliquet arcu dictum. Nam efficitur luctus dictum. Aenean
          ex ipsum, iaculis sed venenatis ut, blandit vel augue. Donec vehicula, lorem tristique consectetur porttitor, risus mauris euismod est, ut gravida arcu lacus sodales ligula. Maecenas sed tempus ipsum. Mauris in augue sit amet mauris feugiat
          semper. Donec rhoncus neque enim, vitae vestibulum dui consectetur ac. Pellentesque posuere vulputate nibh, nec pretium turpis lobortis finibus. Etiam vel magna sed ligula rhoncus vulputate in et est. Praesent rutrum placerat leo ac porta. Aenean
          malesuada, neque eu varius scelerisque, lorem odio tristique leo, rutrum imperdiet tortor enim sit amet quam. Vestibulum at sollicitudin magna. Ut placerat ultrices lectus venenatis maximus. Fusce risus augue, tempor sit amet cursus ac, imperdiet
          a felis. Sed bibendum leo purus, id convallis sapien elementum sed. Donec bibendum tortor ac purus dictum elementum. Cras ut lectus lobortis, maximus est sodales, semper eros. Quisque vehicula feugiat ligula, in ultricies nisi eleifend eu. Fusce
          at nisl a lorem blandit dapibus. Nullam eget pulvinar purus. Mauris fermentum elit et ex pellentesque, quis congue ex ullamcorper. Morbi non orci tellus. Morbi ultrices eros quis orci consectetur rutrum at in est. Nullam bibendum risus purus,
          a aliquet tortor blandit vel. Curabitur tristique pharetra risus ac rhoncus. Maecenas scelerisque nec ante id congue. Donec aliquam est turpis, vel dictum ante imperdiet sit amet. Vestibulum dapibus, elit vel posuere tempus, magna ex dapibus
          sem, et hendrerit metus tortor vitae mauris. Fusce non urna accumsan est dapibus ornare. Curabitur bibendum risus in tortor tincidunt, id auctor dui consequat. Aenean in vulputate eros, sed semper nisi. Fusce eget pretium neque. Cras sollicitudin
          mattis mauris eget consectetur. Donec tincidunt odio pharetra mattis tempor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2 id="opera">Opera</h2>
        <p class="browser-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis vehicula neque. Phasellus consequat risus sed magna hendrerit venenatis. Nulla maximus magna eu velit vestibulum, at aliquet arcu dictum. Nam efficitur luctus dictum. Aenean
          ex ipsum, iaculis sed venenatis ut, blandit vel augue. Donec vehicula, lorem tristique consectetur porttitor, risus mauris euismod est, ut gravida arcu lacus sodales ligula. Maecenas sed tempus ipsum. Mauris in augue sit amet mauris feugiat
          semper. Donec rhoncus neque enim, vitae vestibulum dui consectetur ac. Pellentesque posuere vulputate nibh, nec pretium turpis lobortis finibus. Etiam vel magna sed ligula rhoncus vulputate in et est. Praesent rutrum placerat leo ac porta. Aenean
          malesuada, neque eu varius scelerisque, lorem odio tristique leo, rutrum imperdiet tortor enim sit amet quam. Vestibulum at sollicitudin magna. Ut placerat ultrices lectus venenatis maximus. Fusce risus augue, tempor sit amet cursus ac, imperdiet
          a felis. Sed bibendum leo purus, id convallis sapien elementum sed. Donec bibendum tortor ac purus dictum elementum. Cras ut lectus lobortis, maximus est sodales, semper eros. Quisque vehicula feugiat ligula, in ultricies nisi eleifend eu. Fusce
          at nisl a lorem blandit dapibus. Nullam eget pulvinar purus. Mauris fermentum elit et ex pellentesque, quis congue ex ullamcorper. Morbi non orci tellus. Morbi ultrices eros quis orci consectetur rutrum at in est. Nullam bibendum risus purus,
          a aliquet tortor blandit vel. Curabitur tristique pharetra risus ac rhoncus. Maecenas scelerisque nec ante id congue. Donec aliquam est turpis, vel dictum ante imperdiet sit amet. Vestibulum dapibus, elit vel posuere tempus, magna ex dapibus
          sem, et hendrerit metus tortor vitae mauris. Fusce non urna accumsan est dapibus ornare. Curabitur bibendum risus in tortor tincidunt, id auctor dui consequat. Aenean in vulputate eros, sed semper nisi. Fusce eget pretium neque. Cras sollicitudin
          mattis mauris eget consectetur. Donec tincidunt odio pharetra mattis tempor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2 id="firefox">Firefox</h2>
        <p class="browser-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis vehicula neque. Phasellus consequat risus sed magna hendrerit venenatis. Nulla maximus magna eu velit vestibulum, at aliquet arcu dictum. Nam efficitur luctus dictum. Aenean
          ex ipsum, iaculis sed venenatis ut, blandit vel augue. Donec vehicula, lorem tristique consectetur porttitor, risus mauris euismod est, ut gravida arcu lacus sodales ligula. Maecenas sed tempus ipsum. Mauris in augue sit amet mauris feugiat
          semper. Donec rhoncus neque enim, vitae vestibulum dui consectetur ac. Pellentesque posuere vulputate nibh, nec pretium turpis lobortis finibus. Etiam vel magna sed ligula rhoncus vulputate in et est. Praesent rutrum placerat leo ac porta. Aenean
          malesuada, neque eu varius scelerisque, lorem odio tristique leo, rutrum imperdiet tortor enim sit amet quam. Vestibulum at sollicitudin magna. Ut placerat ultrices lectus venenatis maximus. Fusce risus augue, tempor sit amet cursus ac, imperdiet
          a felis. Sed bibendum leo purus, id convallis sapien elementum sed. Donec bibendum tortor ac purus dictum elementum. Cras ut lectus lobortis, maximus est sodales, semper eros. Quisque vehicula feugiat ligula, in ultricies nisi eleifend eu. Fusce
          at nisl a lorem blandit dapibus. Nullam eget pulvinar purus. Mauris fermentum elit et ex pellentesque, quis congue ex ullamcorper. Morbi non orci tellus. Morbi ultrices eros quis orci consectetur rutrum at in est. Nullam bibendum risus purus,
          a aliquet tortor blandit vel. Curabitur tristique pharetra risus ac rhoncus. Maecenas scelerisque nec ante id congue. Donec aliquam est turpis, vel dictum ante imperdiet sit amet. Vestibulum dapibus, elit vel posuere tempus, magna ex dapibus
          sem, et hendrerit metus tortor vitae mauris. Fusce non urna accumsan est dapibus ornare. Curabitur bibendum risus in tortor tincidunt, id auctor dui consequat. Aenean in vulputate eros, sed semper nisi. Fusce eget pretium neque. Cras sollicitudin
          mattis mauris eget consectetur. Donec tincidunt odio pharetra mattis tempor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="scroll col-12">
        <h2 id="safari">Safari</h2>
        <p class="browser-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis vehicula neque. Phasellus consequat risus sed magna hendrerit venenatis. Nulla maximus magna eu velit vestibulum, at aliquet arcu dictum. Nam efficitur luctus dictum. Aenean
          ex ipsum, iaculis sed venenatis ut, blandit vel augue. Donec vehicula, lorem tristique consectetur porttitor, risus mauris euismod est, ut gravida arcu lacus sodales ligula. Maecenas sed tempus ipsum. Mauris in augue sit amet mauris feugiat
          semper. Donec rhoncus neque enim, vitae vestibulum dui consectetur ac. Pellentesque posuere vulputate nibh, nec pretium turpis lobortis finibus. Etiam vel magna sed ligula rhoncus vulputate in et est. Praesent rutrum placerat leo ac porta. Aenean
          malesuada, neque eu varius scelerisque, lorem odio tristique leo, rutrum imperdiet tortor enim sit amet quam. Vestibulum at sollicitudin magna. Ut placerat ultrices lectus venenatis maximus. Fusce risus augue, tempor sit amet cursus ac, imperdiet
          a felis. Sed bibendum leo purus, id convallis sapien elementum sed. Donec bibendum tortor ac purus dictum elementum. Cras ut lectus lobortis, maximus est sodales, semper eros. Quisque vehicula feugiat ligula, in ultricies nisi eleifend eu. Fusce
          at nisl a lorem blandit dapibus. Nullam eget pulvinar purus. Mauris fermentum elit et ex pellentesque, quis congue ex ullamcorper. Morbi non orci tellus. Morbi ultrices eros quis orci consectetur rutrum at in est. Nullam bibendum risus purus,
          a aliquet tortor blandit vel. Curabitur tristique pharetra risus ac rhoncus. Maecenas scelerisque nec ante id congue. Donec aliquam est turpis, vel dictum ante imperdiet sit amet. Vestibulum dapibus, elit vel posuere tempus, magna ex dapibus
          sem, et hendrerit metus tortor vitae mauris. Fusce non urna accumsan est dapibus ornare. Curabitur bibendum risus in tortor tincidunt, id auctor dui consequat. Aenean in vulputate eros, sed semper nisi. Fusce eget pretium neque. Cras sollicitudin
          mattis mauris eget consectetur. Donec tincidunt odio pharetra mattis tempor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2 id="edge">Edge</h2>
        <p class="browser-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis vehicula neque. Phasellus consequat risus sed magna hendrerit venenatis. Nulla maximus magna eu velit vestibulum, at aliquet arcu dictum. Nam efficitur luctus dictum. Aenean
          ex ipsum, iaculis sed venenatis ut, blandit vel augue. Donec vehicula, lorem tristique consectetur porttitor, risus mauris euismod est, ut gravida arcu lacus sodales ligula. Maecenas sed tempus ipsum. Mauris in augue sit amet mauris feugiat
          semper. Donec rhoncus neque enim, vitae vestibulum dui consectetur ac. Pellentesque posuere vulputate nibh, nec pretium turpis lobortis finibus. Etiam vel magna sed ligula rhoncus vulputate in et est. Praesent rutrum placerat leo ac porta. Aenean
          malesuada, neque eu varius scelerisque, lorem odio tristique leo, rutrum imperdiet tortor enim sit amet quam. Vestibulum at sollicitudin magna. Ut placerat ultrices lectus venenatis maximus. Fusce risus augue, tempor sit amet cursus ac, imperdiet
          a felis. Sed bibendum leo purus, id convallis sapien elementum sed. Donec bibendum tortor ac purus dictum elementum. Cras ut lectus lobortis, maximus est sodales, semper eros. Quisque vehicula feugiat ligula, in ultricies nisi eleifend eu. Fusce
          at nisl a lorem blandit dapibus. Nullam eget pulvinar purus. Mauris fermentum elit et ex pellentesque, quis congue ex ullamcorper. Morbi non orci tellus. Morbi ultrices eros quis orci consectetur rutrum at in est. Nullam bibendum risus purus,
          a aliquet tortor blandit vel. Curabitur tristique pharetra risus ac rhoncus. Maecenas scelerisque nec ante id congue. Donec aliquam est turpis, vel dictum ante imperdiet sit amet. Vestibulum dapibus, elit vel posuere tempus, magna ex dapibus
          sem, et hendrerit metus tortor vitae mauris. Fusce non urna accumsan est dapibus ornare. Curabitur bibendum risus in tortor tincidunt, id auctor dui consequat. Aenean in vulputate eros, sed semper nisi. Fusce eget pretium neque. Cras sollicitudin
          mattis mauris eget consectetur. Donec tincidunt odio pharetra mattis tempor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-padding row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2 id="other">Other browsers</h2>
        <p class="browser-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis vehicula neque. Phasellus consequat risus sed magna hendrerit venenatis. Nulla maximus magna eu velit vestibulum, at aliquet arcu dictum. Nam efficitur luctus dictum. Aenean
          ex ipsum, iaculis sed venenatis ut, blandit vel augue. Donec vehicula, lorem tristique consectetur porttitor, risus mauris euismod est, ut gravida arcu lacus sodales ligula. Maecenas sed tempus ipsum. Mauris in augue sit amet mauris feugiat
          semper. Donec rhoncus neque enim, vitae vestibulum dui consectetur ac. Pellentesque posuere vulputate nibh, nec pretium turpis lobortis finibus. Etiam vel magna sed ligula rhoncus vulputate in et est. Praesent rutrum placerat leo ac porta. Aenean
          malesuada, neque eu varius scelerisque, lorem odio tristique leo, rutrum imperdiet tortor enim sit amet quam. Vestibulum at sollicitudin magna. Ut placerat ultrices lectus venenatis maximus. Fusce risus augue, tempor sit amet cursus ac, imperdiet
          a felis. Sed bibendum leo purus, id convallis sapien elementum sed. Donec bibendum tortor ac purus dictum elementum. Cras ut lectus lobortis, maximus est sodales, semper eros. Quisque vehicula feugiat ligula, in ultricies nisi eleifend eu. Fusce
          at nisl a lorem blandit dapibus. Nullam eget pulvinar purus. Mauris fermentum elit et ex pellentesque, quis congue ex ullamcorper. Morbi non orci tellus. Morbi ultrices eros quis orci consectetur rutrum at in est. Nullam bibendum risus purus,
          a aliquet tortor blandit vel. Curabitur tristique pharetra risus ac rhoncus. Maecenas scelerisque nec ante id congue. Donec aliquam est turpis, vel dictum ante imperdiet sit amet. Vestibulum dapibus, elit vel posuere tempus, magna ex dapibus
          sem, et hendrerit metus tortor vitae mauris. Fusce non urna accumsan est dapibus ornare. Curabitur bibendum risus in tortor tincidunt, id auctor dui consequat. Aenean in vulputate eros, sed semper nisi. Fusce eget pretium neque. Cras sollicitudin
          mattis mauris eget consectetur. Donec tincidunt odio pharetra mattis tempor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="bg-dark text-white mt-4">
    <div class="container-fluid py-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <h4><a href="#top"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>Click here to go the top!</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src=" https://use.fontawesome.com/359ea94094.js"></script>
  <script src="js/tbdjs-main.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm kind of at my wit's end here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite strange. I don't know what am doing. By changing CDN, now your code is working fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tbd.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/hover-min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="pattern-svg-background">
  <div class="col-xl-1-12|auto">
    <div id="top" class="jumbotron">
      <h1 class="display-3">Hello there,buddy!</h1>
      <p class="lead">It is time to choose a browser but there are so many great choices that you get confused on what to pick! </p>
      <hr class="m-y-md">
      <p>This is where I come in! I'm going to explain the pros and cons of most popular(and less popular) browsers. Pick your browser in the menu below!</p>
      <p class="lead">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light rounded mb-3">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav text-md-center nav-justified w-100">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#chrome"><i class="fa fa-chrome fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Google Chrome<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#opera"><i class="fa fa-opera fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Opera</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#safari"><i class="fa fa-safari fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Safari</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#firefox"><i class="fa fa-firefox fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Firefox</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#edge"><i class="fa fa-edge fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Edge</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Other browsers</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#other">Vivaldi</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#other">Midori</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#other">Pale Moon</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-browser-info-text container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2 id="chrome">Google Chrome</h2>
        <p class="browser-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis vehicula neque. Phasellus consequat risus sed magna hendrerit venenatis. Nulla maximus magna eu velit vestibulum, at aliquet arcu dictum. Nam efficitur luctus dictum. Aenean
          ex ipsum, iaculis sed venenatis ut, blandit vel augue. Donec vehicula, lorem tristique consectetur porttitor, risus mauris euismod est, ut gravida arcu lacus sodales ligula. Maecenas sed tempus ipsum. Mauris in augue sit amet mauris feugiat
          sem, et hendrerit metus tortor vitae mauris. Fusce non urna accumsan est dapibus ornare. Curabitur bibendum risus in tortor tincidunt, id auctor dui consequat. Aenean in vulputate eros, sed semper nisi. Fusce eget pretium neque. Cras sollicitudin
          mattis mauris eget consectetur. Donec tincidunt odio pharetra mattis tempor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2 id="opera">Opera</h2>
        <p class="browser-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis vehicula neque. Phasellus consequat risus sed magna hendrerit venenatis. Nulla maximus magna eu velit vestibulum, at aliquet arc
          sem, et hendrerit metus tortor vitae mauris. Fusce non urna accumsan est dapibus ornare. Curabitur bibendum risus in tortor tincidunt, id auctor dui consequat. Aenean in vulputate eros, sed semper nisi. Fusce eget pretium neque. Cras sollicitudin
          mattis mauris eget consectetur. Donec tincidunt odio pharetra mattis tempor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2 id="firefox">Firefox</h2>
        <p class="browser-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis vehicula neque. Phasellus consequat risus sed magna hendrerit venenatis. Nulla maximus magna eu velit vestibulum, at aliquet arcu et hendrerit metus tortor vitae mauris. Fusce non urna accumsan est dapibus ornare. Curabitur bibendum risus in tortor tincidunt, id auctor dui consequat. Aenean in vulputate eros, sed semper nisi. Fusce eget pretium neque. Cras sollicitudin
          mattis mauris eget consectetur. Donec tincidunt odio pharetra mattis tempor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="scroll col-12">
        <h2 id="safari">Safari</h2>
        <p class="browser-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis vehicula neque. Phasellus consequat risus sed magna hendrerit venenatis. Nulla maximus magna eu velit vestibulum, at aliquet arcu dictum. Nam efficitur luctus dictum. Aenean             
          it vel. Curabitur tristique pharetra risus ac rhoncus. Maecenas scelerisque nec ante id congue. Donec aliquam est turpis, vel dictum ante imperdiet sit amet. Vestibulum dapibus, elit vel posuere tempus, magna ex dapibus
          sem, et hendrerit metus tortor vitae mauris. Fusce non urna accumsan est dapibus ornare. Curabitur bibendum risus in tortor tincidunt, id auctor dui consequat. Aenean in vulputate eros, sed semper nisi. Fusce eget pretium neque. Cras sollicitudin
          mattis mauris eget consectetur. Donec tincidunt odio pharetra mattis tempor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2 id="edge">Edge</h2>
        <p class="browser-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis vehicula neque. Phasellus consequat risus sed magna hendrerit venenatis. Nulla maximus magna eu velit vestibulum, at aliquet arcu dictum. Nam efficitur luctus dictum. Aenean
          semper. Donec rhoncus neque enim, vitae vestibulum dui consectetur ac. Pellentesque posuere vulputate nibh, nec pretium turpis lobortis finibus. Etiam vel magna sed ligula rhoncus vulputate in et est. Praesent rutrum placerat leo ac porta. Aenean             
          mattis mauris eget consectetur. Donec tincidunt odio pharetra mattis tempor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-padding row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h2 id="other">Other browsers</h2>
        <p class="browser-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam quis vehicula neque. Phasellus consequat risus sed magna hendrerit venenatis. Nulla maximus magna eu velit vestibulum, at aliquet arcu dictum. Nam efficitur luctus dictum. Aenean             
          mattis mauris eget consectetur. Donec tincidunt odio pharetra mattis tempor.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="bg-dark text-white mt-4">
    <div class="container-fluid py-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <h4><a href="#top"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>Click here to go the top!</a></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
      </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- custom script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-link').click(function() {
    var sectionTo = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(sectionTo).offset().top
    }, 1000);
  });
});
</script>     

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Holy crap,that actually works on Chrome! Thank you so much,man!  PS: JEEESSSSUUUUSSSS CHRIST, the CDN was really the problem with the whole thing! To anyone having the same problem - DON'T USE jQuery Slim 3.2.1 from Bootstrap 4's CDN!!!

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a smooth scroll on navigation click event to respective section, you can achieve it without using any third party plugins.

Find this [fiddler][1] for your reference.

Hope it helps.

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/rajsnd08/qp2L2ycv/
```

Comment: I've already tried this example multiple times with multiple iterations.It doesn't work. jQuery smooth-scroll plugins also don't work for me.

Comment: It has to work. Ok then let me edit your code itself.

Comment: @TKD21 am not able to edit it here, can you pls put it in fiddler and share the url?

Comment: @TKD21 pls refer my updated fiddler in answer. I used your markup and make use of same function to achieve it. It works great.

Comment: @TKD21 I don't get it!

Comment: Post removing script tag and external css, adding my functions works well on your fiddler.

Comment: Nvm got it to dropdown,code works in jsfiddle but doesnt work in my work file and Chrome.